# how to achieve disk write speed as high as fio does?

Tags: linux, benchmarking, disk, solid-state-drive, disk-io

I bought a Highpoint a HBA card with 4 Samsung 960PRO in it.As the official site said this card can perform 7500MB/s in writing and 13000MB/s in reading.

When I test this card with fio in my ubuntu 16.04 system,I got a writing speed of about 7000MB/s,here is my test arguments:

```
sudo fio -filename=/home/xid/raid0_dir0/fio.test -direct=1 -rw=write -ioengine=sync -bs=2k -iodepth=32 -size=100G -numjobs=1 -runtime=100 -time_base=1 -group_reporting -name=test-seq-write
```

I have made a raid0 in the card and made a xfs filesystem.I want to know how to achieve disk writing speed as high as fio performed if I want to use functions such as "open(),read(),write()" or functions such as "fopen(),fread(),fwrite()"  in my console applications.

Comment: Maybe this is a better fit on [Super User SE](https://superuser.com) as this question is not programming related?

Comment: Easiest way is to read and understand the source of the tool (`fio` in this case).  Then you can use similar techniques in your own code.

Comment: ^_^,That is the first idea comes to my head,but it really takes a long time to digest source code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just note that the `fio` job you specified seems a little flawed:

> -direct=1 -rw=write -**ioengine=sync** -bs=2k -**iodepth=32**

(for the sake of simplicity let's assume the dashes are actually double)

The above is asking trying to ask a synchronous ioengine to use an `iodepth` of greater than one. This usually doesn't make sense and the [`iodepth` section of the fio documentation warns about this](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-iodepth):

> **iodepth**=int
>
> Number of I/O units to keep in flight against the file. Note that
>   **increasing iodepth beyond 1 will not affect *synchronous* ioengines**
>   (except for small degrees when verify_async is in use). Even async
>   engines may impose OS restrictions causing the desired depth not to be
>   achieved. [emphasis added]

You didn't post the fio output so we can't tell if you ever achieved an iodepth of greater than one. 7.5GByte/s seems high for such a job and I can't help thinking your filesystem quietly went and did buffering behind your back but who knows? I can't say more because the output of you fio run is unavailable I'm afraid.

Also note the [data fio was writing might not have been random enough to defeat compression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459223/109111) thus helping to achieve an artificially high I/O speed...

Anyway to your main question:

> how to achieve disk write speed as high as fio does?

Your example shows you are telling fio to use an [ioengine that does regular `write` calls](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-ioengine). With this in mind, theoretically you should be able to achieve a similar speed by:

1. Preallocating your file and only writing into the allocated portions of it (so you are not doing extending writes)
2. Fulfilling all the requirements of using `O_DIRECT` (there are strict memory alignment and size constraints that MUST be fulfilled)
3. Making sure your `write` operations are working on buffers writing in chunks of exactly 2048 bytes (or greater so long as they are powers of two)
4. Submitting your `write`s as soon as possible :-)

You may find not using `O_DIRECT` (and thus allowing buffered I/O to do coalescing) is better if for some reason you are unable to submit "large" well aligned buffers every time.